# Aptana and JavaScript/jQuery IDE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide, intellisense

I'm using Aptana for JavaScript and jQuery.

My script files are not being outlined, but I understand that this is a known issue.

When editing JavaScript, is there a way to add simple editing short cuts like:

1. High light a block and comment /or uncomment block.
2. Getting intellisense to recognize Jquery-UI and other libraries?
3. And while I’m here and asking what about the outliner and created code?
   a. What allows JQuery to be recognized and my scripts to not be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Answers to 2. and a.

Aptana cheats. It knows jQuery and uses some local heuristics to guess when something is a jQuery collection, but it does not do data-flow analysis on the javascript to determine the type. That's why jQuery shows up, but jQueryUI and your code don't.

Comment: I found a helper solution that is just plain good practive. Create a namespace(s) for all variables and functions. It will still not include the $(document).ready, but will get tha main stuff.